# How to keep the image's quality after rotating in C#?

Tags: c#, image, rotation

my lecturer required me to code a program that can rotates the image without any transform functions provided by C# library, that means I just could use the method that is provided by [this wiki's link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). My problem is, after rotating, the quality of the image became very bad, like image below.

[image: the left hand side image is the origin]

And here is my code, first part is creating a new bitmap for an image after rotated:

```
            double sin = Math.Abs(Math.Sin(ratio * (Math.PI / 180.0)));
            double cos = Math.Abs(Math.Cos(ratio * (Math.PI / 180.0)));
            bmpOut = new Bitmap((int)(sin * bmpIn.Width + cos * bmpIn.Height), (int)(sin * bmpIn.Height + cos * bmpIn.Width));
```

And here is the code that rotate image

```
        int intHeight = bitmapOri.Height;
        int intWidth = bitmapOri.Width;

        double x_cen = intWidth / 2.0;
        double y_cen = intHeight / 2.0;

        unsafe
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < intWidth; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < intHeight; i++)
                {
                    double x_new = x_cen + (double)((j - x_cen) * Math.Cos(ratio) - (i - y_cen) * Math.Sin(ratio));
                    double y_new = y_cen + (double)((j - x_cen) * Math.Sin(ratio) + (i - y_cen) * Math.Cos(ratio));
                    if (x_new < 0 || y_new < 0 || x_new >= bitmapRes.Width || y_new >= bitmapRes.Height)
                        continue;
                    bitmapRes.SetPixel((int)x_new, (int)y_new, bitmapOri.GetPixel(j, i));
                }
            }
        }
```

Can you please tell me that what is the fraud(s) in my code, what's wrong with it, many thanks for your helps.

Comment: you need to account for the height to width ratio when you rotate.  if you rotate an image that is 4 wide and 3 tall 90 degrees without adjusting, you will end up squishing 4 into 3, and spreading 3 into 4.  so either adjust the way you are rotating, or figure out a way to rotate the object the image is in rather than the image itself.

Comment: The root of the problem is in your casting. When you rotate a point around an origin, the point will in the overwhelming majority of the cases result in a decimal number, but when you cast the coordinates to (int) you are discarding that information. This results in some pixels getting set more than once while others don't get set at all. The simple solution is to round rather than truncate, but a more robust solution is the one in ZenWu's answer.

Comment: As a side note, you are also operating within an `unsafe` block, but none of your code requires that to be the case.

Comment: An other question. what happens with my rotate function when the image does not rotate through its center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### problem

the double to int operation could cause some pixel set more than one times and some pixels not set

### solution

try the opposite way

1. foreach pixel in rotated image
2. compute their location in original image
3. if the location is not integer, average around four pixels by distance

### details

how to compute the location in original image

1. let rotate pivot be O, considering point A as a pixel in target image
2. **OA** could be written as t * rotate(alpha, **OX**). **OX** is a normalized vector started from point O. it means that **OA** vector could be viewed as(or get by) rotated **alpha** angle from **OA** , and it could have a special length(**t**). And **OA** real value would be (t * cos(alpha), t * sin(alpha))
3. assume OA was actually rotated OB, since it is in target image rotated from original image, so OB could be written as t * rotate(alpha+beta, **X**). It means **OA** was one rotate operation different between **OB**. It's a little strange. But it is correct and useful.
4. let's do the real work now. **OB** actual value is (t * cos(alpha+beta), t * sin(alpha + beta)).
5. let us focus on X coordinate, which equals t * cos(alpha) * sin(beta) + t * sin(alpha) + t * cos(beta), and turn back to watch **OA** coordinate. it infers that X(**OB**) = sin(beta) * X(**OA**) + cos(beta) * Y(**OA**). Y coordinate is the same.

Comment: The technical term for step 3 is "bilinear interpolation".

Comment: Which formula can help me to find the location on the original image in step 2?

Comment: @iamatsundere181 just the reverse function of your formula, try it yourself maybe since it's a exercise

Comment: An other question. what happens with my rotate function when the image does not rotate through its center?

Comment: @iamatsundere181 I'm so sorry that i didn't really check your rotate formula. I edited the answer and add some details about step 2. The rotate pivot was also mentioned